# Post new record into AspNetUsers from another controller (Web api)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I want to POST new user to AspNetUsers using webApi
Here is what I'm trying to do:
[HttpPost]

```
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> POST([FromBody]ICollection<ApplicationUser> employees)
        {

        employees.First().PasswordHash = HashPassword(employees.First().PasswordHash);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }


        foreach (var item in employees)
        {
            db.Users.Add(item);
        }
        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            Exception raise = dbEx;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    // raise a new exception nesting
                    // the current instance as InnerException
                    raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                }
            }
            throw raise;
        }
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
        (new CustomUserStore(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<CustomRole, int>
            (new CustomRoleStore(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        manager.AddToRoles(employees.First().Id, "User");

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employees.First().Id  }, employees);
    }
    public static string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        if (password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
        }


        byte[] salt;
        byte[] subkey;
        using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize, PBKDF2IterCount))
        {
            salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
            subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
        }

        var outputBytes = new byte[1 + SaltSize + PBKDF2SubkeyLength];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 1, SaltSize);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 1 + SaltSize, PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
    }
```

I tried to test it using Postman and here is what I'm getting:

****[ArgumentNullException]: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value, String valueType, String issuer, String originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, String propertyKey, String propertyValue)
   at System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ClaimsIdentityFactory`2.<CreateAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at DataInGrid.Models.ApplicationUser.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\DataInGrid\DataInGrid\Models\IdentityModels.cs:line 18
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at DataInGrid.Providers.ApplicationOAuthProvider.<GrantResourceOwnerCredentials>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\DataInGrid\DataInGrid\Providers\ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs:line 42
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.<InvokeTokenEndpointResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrantAsync>d__3f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a hot mess. I'm not sure what in the world you're doing. First, `UserManager` and `RoleManager` are services. You never new them up; instead, you inject them into your class:

```
[ApiController]
public UserApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UserApiController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, to create a new user, you should be using:

```
await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

That will take care of hashing the password for you, as well as other necessary tasks such as normalizing the username, email address, etc.

Next, you should not be binding the post to `ApplicationUser`. That's your entity, and it's not appropriate for something like a create user request. Namely, it has no `Password` property to hold the user's desired password, pre-hashed. Instead, you should create a view model/DTO class with just the properties you want to be able to submit. That could be as little as just an email address and a password.

Then, you map the posted data onto an instance of your `ApplicationUser` entity:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
{
    Email = model.Email
    // etc.
};
```

Then:

```
await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Since you're posting a list of users to create, you'd simply iterate over that and do the same thing for each one.

Comment: Thank you, I already used something like this. What I want to do is to send data from grid (as Json result) to Post function and store it in AspNetUsers !

Comment: And? *How* you're sending the data is inconsequential; the method for persisting it remains the same.

Comment: That's solved by CreateAsync. It handles the password hashing and will do it the same every time. Your issue may be down to not sharing the data protection key store, which will be necessary for different applications to encrypt things in the same way.

Comment: I didn't understand the concept very well ! Now I do :) Thank you so much